# Notation $ord(\alpha)$ find $ord(\alpha)=30$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following question :

Find the four missing places in the permutation in $\alpha\in S_{11}$ so that $ord(\alpha)=30$

$$\alpha(1)=?$$
$$\alpha(2)=?$$
$$\alpha(3)=9$$
$$\alpha(4)=?$$
$$\alpha(5)=5$$
$$\alpha(6)=?$$
$$\alpha(7)=3$$
$$\alpha(8)=4$$
$$\alpha(9)=2$$
$$\alpha(10)=6$$
$$\alpha(11)=8$$

I'm not sure what is the notation $ord(\alpha)$ is it equal to $o(\alpha)=30$?

Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's the order of $\alpha$, the smallest (strictly) positive integer $k$ such that $\alpha^k = \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, I see that exactly what I thought, yet how could how to find the four missing places? while I know that $ord(\alpha)$ should be $30$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can find the order of the permutation by writing it in disjoint cyclic notation and taking the LCM of all of the disjoint cycles. Maybe that and guess and check will help you find what the four missing places will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The order of a permutation is the smallest common multiple of the order of its disjoint cycles. Since $30 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ and we are in $S_{11}$ then we need cycles of orders $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n$ such that
$$\sum_i c_i = 11 \qquad \text{scm}(c_i) = 30$$

One can check that the only options are either to have a $5$-cycle, a $3$-cycle, a $2$-cycle and a $1$-cycle; or a $6$-cycle and a $5$-cycle, but since $\alpha(5) = 5$ the last option is not possible.

> You should get $\alpha = (6,10)(4,11,8)(1,7,3,9,2)$.

Comment: A $5$-cycle and a $6$-cycle also works. (In principle, here we have a fixed point, so that is ruled out.)

Comment: And as a note for the OP, it's highly likely that there isn't a *unique* solution here.